# How to wait for store data when component was reloaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, routes

Currently I'm writing an application in which there is a table and a detail page accessed by route element. I do use the params element to select required detail, the page displays without the problem and the data of selected element is presented. My problem is that after reload the store state isn't loaded as fast as component is and the mapping of the page is gone. What should I do to persist the state of my user details component after reloading the page. I would like not to use the localstorage neither another library.

```
<Route path="/table/:userId" element={<Details />} />

<td>
                                    <button>
                                        <Link to={`/table/${user.id}`}>
                                            Details
                                        </Link>
                                    </button>
                                </td>

const Details = (props) => {
    const {userId} = useParams()

    console.log(props)
     console.log(userId)

   const user = useSelector((state) => state.users.data.find((u) => u.id === Number(userId)))
   
    return (
        <>
            <div className="css">
                <div className="css">
                    <h2>Some details</h2>
                    <p>Name: {detail.name}</p>
                    <p>Email: {detail.email}</p>
                    <p>City: {detail.city}</p>
                    <p>Country: {detail.country}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
    return {
        data: state.users.data,
        error: state.users.error
    }}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Details)

export const fetchUsers = createAsyncThunk('table/fetchUsers', async () => {
    const data = await fetcher('http://localhost:3001/users/')
    return data
})
```

I' m trying to fetch the data once more in useEffect element but there is still error that `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')`. It's my first try, the other was to try mapDispatch ToProps method but it still failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all "detail" doesn't seem to defined, do you mean "user"?

Second: your data is fetched asynchronously, so your component would be rendered before the data is fetched, i.e "detail" is undefined when the component is rendered, thus the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')".

Either render your component conditionally something like:

```
if(!user) return;
return(
<>
        <div className="css">
            <div className="css">
                <h2>Some details</h2>
                <p>Name: {user.name}</p>
                <p>Email: {user.email}</p>
                <p>City: {user.city}</p>
                <p>Country: {user.country}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>)
```

or use optional chaining (?.) :

```
<div className="css">
            <div className="css">
                <h2>Some details</h2>
                <p>Name: {user?.name}</p>
                <p>Email: {user?.email}</p>
                <p>City: {user?.city}</p>
                <p>Country: {user?.country}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This way if user is undefined its properties won't accessed, and no error will be raised

Comment: Hey thank You for help the optional chaining operator helped to wait for the data to be accessible.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass data using 'query' parameter

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/link

[image]

Comment: I'll look up into this attribute, thank You